# Visual Basic, Microsoft Access and Excel

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to plot a chart of y against x in visual basic 2012 with the values from microsoft access 2007. Could anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: Have you done some research before asking?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [.NET Charting API](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11001), the *build in* windows charting COM object as described [in this article](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/10/18/charting-with-vb-net-2010/#!prettyPhoto).
or a third party .NET chart library for example from [this CP article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5431/A-flexible-charting-library-for-NET).

MSCharts is the formerly Dundas Charts, which are really good. Have a look:

- [here for more Info, the same question as yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201977/which-net-charting-library-should-i-use)
- [and here for a MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh297118%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)